# MongoDB: Queries running 3x slow on Azure Serverless Mongodb compared to MongoDb Atlas Free Tier server

Tags: mongodb, azure, cosmos-db

I have a database in MongoDB Atlas using the free tier package. 
I recently transferred my data to Azure Serverless CosmosDB for MongoDB using mongoexport.

After the data transfer, I've noticed that the query times have increased significantly. Specifically, the queries are now taking 3 times longer in Azure CosmosDB compared to their original performance in MongoDB Atlas.

**Details:**

**Database size:** 623 MB
**Types of queries:** Get Queries / Facet Aggregation 
**Indexing:** It Seems Same as the old server

**Questions:**

Are there known performance differences between MongoDB Atlas and Azure Serverless CosmosDB for MongoDB that could account for this increase in query time? 
Could the mongoexport process have impacted the data in a way that affects performance? 
What steps can I take to diagnose and improve the performance of my queries in Azure CosmosDB?

Comment: As first action you should compare the explain plans.

Comment: What compute resources are allocated to each of those?